# How to remove undefined object error and redirect user based on location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a geolocation feature that redirects users to pages for their respective cities. I have used Google Maps API and HTML5 Geolocation to try and implement this. On running the below script, address is shown to be an object in the console. However, when I try to make the comparison on the subsequent line, I get an error saying Undefined is not an object(evaluating 'address.results'. How can I make the code work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var GOOGLE_API_KEY = "mykey";
  var lat, lng;
  var geocoder;
  var geoCodingUrl;
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
  }
  function successFunction(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    var geoCodingUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + lat + "," + lng + "&key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY;
    console.log(geoCodingUrl); 
    var address = $.get(geoCodingUrl);
console.log(address);
  if (address.results[0].formatted_address[4] == "Mumbai, Maharashtra, India") {
    window.location = "url";
  } 
  if(address.results.long_name == "Bangalore, India"){
    window.location = "url";
  } 
  if(address.results.long_name == "Jaipur, India") {
    window.location = "url";
  }
  }

function errorFunction() {
   alert ("Geocoder failed");
}

</script>
```

Comment: Check for errors on the `$.get`, that was not allowed from javascript last I checked.  Although it does seem to be working in my answer to [this question:Google maps javascript implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795234/google-maps-javascript-implementation)

Comment: How do I check for errors on $.get?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.get({url:geoCodingUrl,success:function(response){
    var address=response.results;
    if (address[0].formatted_address[4] == "Mumbai, Maharashtra, India") {
    window.location = "url";
    } 
   if(address[0].long_name == "Bangalore, India"){
     window.location = "url";
   } 
   if(address[0].long_name == "Jaipur, India") {
     window.location = "url";
   }
}
})
```

Comment: This caused GeoCoder to fail.

Comment: try the $.get() with proper url and success callback